# Step into 3rd party components

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have a few 3rd party components (with source) that I'd like to step into their code for debug purposes. For all of the components, I've added their source folder to the Tools>Environment Variables>Language>Library section, but when I step into their functions I never get taken to their source code but instead to System.Classes or similar.

I'm doing this on a new Debug Mode application.

Comment: It is not enough to just point at the source folder. You have to recompile the components with debug symbols enabled before you can then step into the source code

Comment: Maybe it helps if you don't use runtime packages + the debug symbols so everything gets definitly recompiled.

Comment: Maybe the precompiled dcu from the library are seen by the compiler. Make sure you BUILD the application, not just compile. Look in the application's dcu directory if you find the 3rd party component dcu you just compiled (see the timestamp).

Comment: Yeah they (the dcus) are not there. Is there a way I can tell the compiler I'd like it to compile a separate folder of components?